# Identifying date types in Spreadsheet::ParseExcel

Tags: excel, perl, parsing, spreadsheet

We are migrating from a MS Excel OLE based module to `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel` (or similar). As we have hundreds of programs using our module we'd prefer that we provide a drop in replacement i.e. the data returned is identical.

The problem is dates - using Excel we get a `Win32::OLE::Variant` object of type `VT_DATE`. As a workaround we can construct this manually by checking `$cell->type() eq 'Date'` and returning the object.

**The problem is that the type is not reliably set, so we can't always do this.**

The `Date` type is set in two places. This is the logic used in `FmtDefault.pm`:

```
if (   ( ( $iFmtIdx >= 0x0E ) && ( $iFmtIdx <= 0x16 ) )
    || ( ( $iFmtIdx >= 0x2D ) && ( $iFmtIdx <= 0x2F ) ) )
{
    return "Date";
}
```

and if this check fails and we get `Numeric`, then it does a backup check in `ParseExcel.pm`:

```
if ( $FmtStr =~ m{^[dmy][-\\/dmy]*$}i ) {
    $rhKey{Type} = "Date";
}
```

However a number of common format strings are not working, for example:

```
[$-C09]dddd\\,\\ d\\ mmmm\\ yyyy;@ i.e. Sunday, 24 January 1982
d/m/yyyy;@ i.e. 24/1/1982
```

I've checked the Excel specification at openoffice.org and also read guides such as http://jonvonderheyden.net/excel/a-comprehensive-guide-to-number-formats-in-excel/#date_code and it seems that the below rule will match a date format string:

A string with d, m, or y characters, which are not between "" or [], not preceded with \ unless it's a \\, and not followed by - or *.

**This seems very complicated and error-prone. Is there a better way?**

It seems `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Utility::ExcelFmt()` flags a date format under `$format_mode` so perhaps this logic can be modified to return the flag? But I'd prefer something ready to go without changing the `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel` modules if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know what columns are supposed to be dates?

In my usage, I do, and convert them with:

```
$val = $cell->unformatted();
# if it was properly set as a Date cell, the value will be a number of days since 1900 or 1904
# that we can convert to a date, regardless of the format they were shown.
if ( $val =~ /^[0-9]{5}(?:\.[0-9]+)?\z/ ) {
    $date = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Utility::ExcelFmt( 'YYYY-MM-DD', $val, $wb->{'Flg1904'} );
}
else {
    $val = $cell->value();
    $val =~ s/^'//;
    # try parsing it with Date::Manip, which handles all common formats (see its ParseDateString doc)
    use Date::Manip ();
    Date::Manip::Date_Init("TZ=GMT","DateFormat=US");
    $date = Date::Manip::UnixDate( $val, '%Y-%m-%d' );
}
```

Update: sounds like you are best off modifying ExcelFmt, something like this (untested):

```
--- Utility.pm.orig 2014-12-17 07:16:06.609942082 -0800
+++ Utility.pm  2014-12-17 07:18:14.453965764 -0800
@@ -69,7 +69,7 @@
 #
 sub ExcelFmt {

-    my ( $format_str, $number, $is_1904, $number_type, $want_subformats ) = @_;
+    my ( $format_str, $number, $is_1904, $number_type, $want_subformats, $want_format_mode ) = @_;

     # Return text strings without further formatting.
     return $number unless $number =~ $qrNUMBER;
@@ -956,8 +956,14 @@
     $result =~ s/^\$\-/\-\$/;
     $result =~ s/^\$ \-/\-\$ /;

-    # Return color and locale strings if required.
-    if ($want_subformats) {
+    # Return format mode and/or color and locale strings if required.
+    if ( $want_subformats && $want_format_mode ) {
+        return ( $result, $color, $locale, $format_mode );
+    }
+    elsif ($want_format_mode) {
+        return ( $result, $format_mode );
+    }
+    elsif ($want_subformats) {
         return ( $result, $color, $locale );
     }
     else {
```

Be sure to submit it to the [maintainer](http://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Spreadsheet-ParseExcel) for inclusion in a later release.

Comment: Unfortunately it's entirely arbitrary. The existing codebase just reads the Excel and returns each row as a hash of values keyed by the column name. We detect dates using 'ref' or a similar method on the variable and call ->Date(...) to format them if required. For new work we could definitely require the programmer to supply a type but it won't work for the legacy code base.

Comment: Thanks I was leaning towards that, possibly with a $$date_format to avoid modifying the return values. I'll see if anyone else has a better idea otherwise will be happy to accept this soon.